# Определить что элементы одной коллекции являются квадратными корнями другой

Tags: c#, алгоритм, linq, ienumerable

Подскажите можно-ли написать более оптимальный алгоритм. Задача звучит так:

> Нужно проверить что все в коллекции numbers являются квадратными корнями чисел в коллекции squares. Коллекции отсортированы по возрастанию и не имеют отрицательных значений.

**update: если коллекции разной длины то считаем это как false**

> Примеры входных данных и ответы:
>   **IN: {1, 2}, {1, 4} OUT: TRUE**
>
> **IN: {1, 3, 5}, {1, 9, 25, 25} OUT: FALSE**

Сигнатура функции:

```
bool TestForSquares(IEnumerable<int> numbers, IEnumerable<int> squares)
```

Моё решение:

```
public static bool TestForSquares(IEnumerable<int> numbers, IEnumerable<int> squares) {
    var isFirstIteration = true;
    var numbersEnumerator = numbers.GetEnumerator();
    var squaresEnumerator = squares.GetEnumerator();

    while (true) {
        bool numberHasNext = numbersEnumerator.MoveNext();
        bool squareHasNext = squaresEnumerator.MoveNext();

        if(numberHasNext != squareHasNext) {
            // случай когда две коллекции имеют разный размер

            return false;
        }

        if(!numberHasNext && !squareHasNext) {

            if (isFirstIteration) {
                // случай когда две коллекции пусты
                return false;
            }

            break;
        }

        var testData = numbersEnumerator.Current * numbersEnumerator.Current;
        if(testData != squaresEnumerator.Current) {
            return false;
        }

        isFirstIteration = false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

p.s.

Так же интересует решение с той же оптимальностью но не такое многословное.

Comment: {1, 5, 3}, {1, 25, 9, 9 } - а где обещанная сортировка по возрастанию?

Comment: Да упустил сейчас поправлю

Answer (score 1):

В C# сейчас есть аналог питоновского Zip, так что можно коротко и просто проверять примерно так:

```
coll1.Zip(coll2).All(x => x.First * x.First == x.Second)
```

Но проверку на совпадение длины коллекций надо делать дополнительно. А вот делать эту проверку до или после сравнения элементов коллекций - это зависит от природы коллекций. Если это готовые массивы или там списки, то можно проверить длину заранее, так будет быстрее всего работать. А если это потоковые данные, и особенно если их вообще нельзя перебирать второй раз, то тут решение с Zip вообще не подойдёт, наверное.

Answer (score 0):

Может быть можно возвести в квадрат все элементы одного списка, а затем проверить, содержит ли один список все элементы второго, используя метод Intersect:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274541/check-if-one-ienumerable-contains-all-elements-of-another-ienumerable ?

Comment: Ок а если у вас в первом же элементе нет совпадений, тогда получается что все что вы возводили в квадрат коту под хвост?

Comment: В приведенной в вопросе постановке задачи не сказано, что коллекции равны по размеру. Требуется проверить, являются ли все `squares` квадратными корнями из `numbers`, но не утверждается, что все `numbers` имеют соответствующий квадратный корень в `squares`.  Вывод: размер `number` должен быть не меньше размера `squares`, но может быть больше. И несовпадение может быть и в первом и во втором, и в сто двадцать третьем элементе...

Comment: В задании написано что ВСЕ в коллекции `squares` является квадратными корнями из `numbers`, то есть коллекция покрывает ВСЕ из `numbers`

Comment: Сейчас дополню вопрос что бы не было недопонимания

Comment: @VasyaMilovidov то, что ВСЕ в коллекции `squares` является квадратными корнями из `numbers` никоим образом не означает, что они покрывают ВСЮ коллекцию `numbers`. Но дополнение действительно снимает неоднозначность. В качестве примера: `squares = [1,2,4]; numbers = [1,4,9,16]` Все `squares` являются квадратными корнями из `numbers`, а значит удовлетворяют начальной постановке задачи. Но остается число 9, для которого квадратного корня не приведено в `squares`